# Select option and change class ul li

Tags: jquery

my code

```
 <select id="jform_parent_id" name="jform[parent_id]">
        <option value="1">Public</option>
        <option value="8">- Admingruppe</option>
        <option value="9">- Guest</option>
        <option value="2">- Projektgruppe</option>
    </select>
    <ul class="chzn-results">
        <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Public</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">- Admingruppe</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">- Guest</li>
        <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">- Projektgruppe</li>
    </ul>
```

I want to :
select option value =2 
add the class result-selected to ul li data-option-array-index="3"
remove the class result-selected everywhere else

thanks for helping

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easier than you think. All you need to do is:

```
$(function () {
  // On change of the select...
  $("#jform_parent_id").change(function () {
    // Get the current selected index.
    var sIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    // Now find the <li> with correct data-option-array-index and add the class.
    $(".result-selected").removeClass("result-selected");
    $('li[data-option-array-index="' + (sIndex) + '"]').addClass("result-selected");
  });
});
```

Full Snippet here:

```js
$(function () {
  // On change of the select...
  $("#jform_parent_id").change(function () {
    // Get the current selected index.
    var sIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    // Now find the <li> with correct data-option-array-index and add the class.
    $(".result-selected").removeClass("result-selected");
    $('li[data-option-array-index="' + (sIndex) + '"]').addClass("result-selected");
  }).val("2").trigger("change");
});
```

```css
.result-selected {background: #99f;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="jform_parent_id" name="jform[parent_id]">
  <option value="1">Public</option>
  <option value="8">- Admingruppe</option>
  <option value="9">- Guest</option>
  <option value="2">- Projektgruppe</option>
</select>
<ul class="chzn-results">
  <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Public</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">- Admingruppe</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">- Guest</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">- Projektgruppe</li>
</ul>
```

**Update:** Used a preselected value on page load.

Comment: thanks a lot Praveen Kumar !  
but I need to pre select value 2 on page load ,I want it to be my default  selected value

Comment: @ErickBoileau Use this way  `<option value="2" selected>- Projektgruppe</option>`. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: @ErickBoileau Check my answer.

Comment: thanks but thats my problem, how to add selected to value 2 ?

Comment: I have no idea why it works here and not on my website
I cannot find in your code how you select option value = 2
thanks anyway !

Comment: @ErickBoileau We can talk in chat to make it work... Could be something else on the event listener. I can help you.

Comment: @ErickBoileau The code is at the end of the event listener: `}).val("2").trigger("change");`

Comment: @ErickBoileau Please update that code in your website and lemme know.

Comment: the code now on my website : 

<script>
jQuery(function($) {  
 // On change of the select...
  $("#jform_parent_id").change(function () {
    // Get the current selected index.
    var sIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    // Now find the <li> with correct data-option-array-index and add the class.
    $(".result-selected").removeClass("result-selected");
    $('li[data-option-array-index="' + (sIndex) + '"]').addClass("result-selected");
  }).val("2").trigger("change");
});</script>

Comment: in chat ?  where ?

Answer (score 0):

I created same solution for one of my project.

It sync user event between custom ul li dropdown with default select option. So if user update/click on li same will be sync with select.

Working URL : https://codepen.io/VijayDhanvai/pen/gOBogLM

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  var syncSelectOnLiClick = function(elSelected){
     $('.styled-select select.dropdown').val(elSelected);
     $('.styled-select select.dropdown').trigger('change');  
  }
  
  $('.styled-select select.dropdown').on('change', function(){
      //console.log($(this).val());
      if($(this).val() != "Year"){
        $('.dropdownMonth').prop("disabled", false);
      }else{
        $('.dropdownMonth').prop("disabled", true);
      }
  });
    
  $('.target-list-container li').on('click', function(){
      var elSelected = $(this).text();
      //console.log('call ', elSelected);
     syncSelectOnLiClick(elSelected);
  });
});
```

```js
;(function($) {    
    $.fn.listFromSelect = function(options) {
    var defaults = {};
    
    // Create an unordered list that corresponds to a select, giving the li that corresponds to the selected option an active class
    var init = function(el) {
      $el = $(el);
      $el.options = $.extend({},defaults, options);
            $el.data('listFromSelect', $el); // save a reference to the element this was called on
      
      $el.ul = $('<ul class="listFromSelect"></ul>');
      if(options.container) {
        options.container.append($el.ul);  
      } else {
                $el.ul.insertAfter(el);
      }
      
      $el.find('option').each(function() {
        // get the value of this option
        var val = $(this).val();
        
        // if this is the selected option, add "active" class
        $el.ul.append('<li data-value="'+val+'"' + ($el.val()==val?"class='active'":"") + '>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
      });
      
      $el.on('change', update);
    };
    
    // Go through each of the lis that were created and update the class of the new active one
    var update = function(e) {
      var $el = $(this).data('listFromSelect');
      $el.ul.find('li').each(function() {
        var $li = $(this);
        if($li.data('value') == $el.val()) {
          $el.ul.find('.active').removeClass('active');
          $li.addClass('active');
          return;
        }
      });
    };
    
        return this.each(function(i){
      init(this);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $(".styled-select select").listFromSelect({
    container: $(".target-list-container")
  });
  $("select.dropdownMonth").listFromSelect({
    container: $(".target-list-container-month")
  });
});




$('document').ready(function(){
  var syncSelectOnLiClick = function(elSelected){
     $('.styled-select select.dropdown').val(elSelected);
     $('.styled-select select.dropdown').trigger('change');  
  }
  
  $('.styled-select select.dropdown').on('change', function(){
      //console.log($(this).val());
      if($(this).val() != "Year"){
        $('.dropdownMonth').prop("disabled", false);
      }else{
        $('.dropdownMonth').prop("disabled", true);
      }
  });
    
  $('.target-list-container li').on('click', function(){
      var elSelected = $(this).text();
      //console.log('call ', elSelected);
     syncSelectOnLiClick(elSelected);
  });
});
```

```css
.col {
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Styling select box from https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx */

body{
      background: #1d1e22;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
select{
  padding : 5px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 240px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #3f3f3f;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="styled-select">
    <select class="dropdown">
      <option value="Year">Year</option>
      <option value="2022">2022</option>
      <option value="2023">2023</option>
      <option value="2024">2024</option>
    </select>
    
    
  </div>
  <select disabled class="dropdownMonth">
      <option>Month</option>
      <option value="1">Jan</option>
      <option value="2">Feb</option>
      <option value="3">Mar</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col target-list-container"></div>
<div class="col target-list-container-month"></div>
```